# create gcloud configuration from json file

Tags: gcloud

I have downloaded my gcloud configs as json (with *gcloud config configurations list --format=json*). Then I picked up one config out from the collection returned, and updated all the features/flags I want in that json and saved as a file. Now I want to create a new configuration with this updated JSON file, how can I do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: AFAIK there is no command to read the JSON file. Create a feature request: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: It seems (!?) as though this could be achieved with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq) with possibly a little more shell scripting fu to generate the commands. For a specific config (name), for each section (e.g. `compute`) for each property (e.g. `zone`) if the value exists and isn't null map it to `gcloud config set {SECTION}/{PROPERTY} {VALUE}`. Pipe the results to a file to sanity check before playing. I think there's not even a way to batch `config set` commands which would be useful/required.

Comment: How did you download the output on running gcloud config configurations list --format=json? This command lists all the active and inactive configurations list in gcloud in the specified json format but does not attempt to download anything. So you must have downloaded the JSON formatted list someway, and then updated one of the configs out of the list and saved as file. Please mention the details, as I am trying to reproduce your issue so that I can help you with my best effort.

Answer (score 2):

**Please test this thoroughly; improvements welcome**

Requires: [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

- filter by (configuration) `name=="foo"`
- convert `.properties` object into an array `{"key":.., "value":[...]}`
- map to `{"section":...,"properties"...}` converting values to an array and filtering `null`
- map the resulting `{"section":...,"properties":{"key":...,"value":...}`
- into a `gcloud config set {section}/${properties[key]} ${properties[value]}`
- returning the array as a list of strings

> **NOTE** There ought to be a way to do this with a single `map`: capturing the `section` value and then for each property key:value pair (where value != `null`) emitting the `gcloud config set` command

```sh
FILTER='.[]
|select(.name=="foo")
|.properties|to_entries
|map(
  {
    "section": .key,
    "properties":.value|to_entries|.[]|select(.value!=null)
  }
)
|map(
  "gcloud config set "+.section+"/"+.properties["key"]+" "+.properties["value"]
)
|.[]'

# Or cat /path/to/your/saved.json
gcloud config configurations list --format=json \
| jq -r "${FILTER}"
```

Example: https://jqplay.org/s/ZO_6urQma8

You could pipe the output into a script and check the script before running it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you are on a Unix-like machine, and that your configurations are stored in `~/.config/gcloud/configurations`.

I'm also assuming that you created the original JSON output by running something similar to the following, and then editing the file in-place:

```
gcloud config configurations activate SOME_CONFIG
gcloud config list --format=json > newconfig.json
```

First, create the new configuration that you want to populate:

```
gcloud config configurations create newconfig
```

You can confirm that this file was created by running:

```
ls ~/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_newconfig
```

Next, use this hidden command to convert the JSON file to config format, and overwrite the configuration file:

```
gcloud meta list-from-json newconfig.json --format=config > ~/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_newconfig
```

You can confirm that things are as expected by running:

```
gcloud config configurations activate newconfig
gcloud config list
```